# Why are some Strange TF2 items showing as 'Restriction'?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, steam-community-market

In this morning, when I was browsing strange items on community market I noticed some of them listed separately as "restriction".So far I can't see no difference between normal strange. Also I see no update notes on anywhere to create new item quality.

Here is a example listings:

- [On search](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_440_Type%5B%5D=any&appid=440&q=strange+festive+professional+knife)
- [item itself](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/restriction%20Professional%20Killstreak%20Festive%20Knife?filter=strange)

My question is, what is the difference between normal Strange weapons and restriction Stranges? also should they worth more or less?

Comment: It could be that they have a [Strange Filter](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Filter) applied to them.  I can't tell, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the TF2 schema changed in a way that looks like an error on Valve's part, causing the "friendly name" for the Strange quality to be "restriction" instead of "Strange":

```
"qualityNames": {
    "Normal": "Normal",
    "rarity1": "Genuine",
    "rarity2": "rarity2",
    "vintage": "Vintage",
    "rarity3": "rarity3",
    "rarity4": "Unusual",
    "Unique": "Unique",
    "community": "map",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "selfmade": "Self-Made",
    "customized": "Customized",
    "strange": "restriction",
    "completed": "Completed",
    "haunted": "Haunted",
    "collectors": "Collector's"
},
```

The line `"strange": "restriction"` used to read `"strange": "Strange"`.

Any software that uses the TF2 schema as the authoritative source for item (including quality) information will suffer this same bug and label *all* Strange-quality items as "restriction" instead.  (If only some are being labeled this way then the software might be caching the titles for some items, so those would be displaying correctly since their titles were put together from the raw item data before the schema change.)

Note the similar error for the `community` quality.

---

I have one system that refreshes the schema periodically, serving it up to my own software when they need the schema (to reduce bandwidth to Valve and generally be a good netizen) so I was able to fix the problem in my own software by disabling the automatic schema updating process and manually editing the schema to reflect the proper quality names.

---

**Update 2015-06-01:** The latest version of the schema no longer shows this problem, so the issue is resolved on Valve's side.

Comment: That's an... interesting bug.  Makes me wonder if someone accidentally updated the TF2 schema instead of the CS:GO or DOTA2 schema.

Comment: @Powerlord It's possible. I can say that I've certainly seen stranger bugs from Valve, so this is about par for the course. They routinely do stuff that breaks my applications for no apparent reason -- sometimes it gets fixed (as in this case) and sometimes it doesn't and I have to grudgingly work around their weirdness.

Answer (score 4):

The "restriction" item has been modified with a Strange part that counts the killings of medics with a ready Übercharge, while the others are a "plain" version of the same item.

An item of this kind is worth more because the [Strange parts](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_part) aren't easy to obtain, since you can only get them from a crate with a very low drop chance.

Comment: Also you can tell what item has what part by clicking on the item listing.

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/restriction%20Professional%20Killstreak%20Baby%20Face%27s%20Blaster Please look at the first item, I cant see any strange part on it to make different from any other normal strange item ?

Comment: If you've looked through the list, one of the knives in the normal (non-restricted) list has Medics Killed, Engineers Killed, and Snipers Killed strange parts.